# Wordpress random post loop only for some posts of an category

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a simple way to say "integrate **post 1 till 10** from **category MyCat** in a **random loop**"? I ask, because I dont want that the random loop integrate all my posts of a category. Thats the problem with this script:

```
<?php query_posts(array(
  'showposts' => 1,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'category_name' => 'MyCat'
));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

What I need is something like this:

```
<?php query_posts(array(
  'showposts' => 1,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'category_name' => 'MyCat'
  'post_number_of_category' => '1-10'    <-- something like this
));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you want a random order then what counts as the first post in the category?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `get_posts` and the `posts_per_page`/`numberposts` option?

```
<?php

$rand_posts = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'category_name' => 'MyCat'
));

foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post );
  the_post();
}; ?>
```

According to WordPress, query_posts is [inefficient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), and showposts [may be deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Comment: Thx for support, but this only counts the number of posts, I need a post selection (I have updated my question on top).

Comment: @Pepe what version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: I use 4.3.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

First hit on Google: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-random-post

```
<?php query_posts('orderby=rand&showposts=1&cat=75,76,77'); ?>
```

Comment: Also thx for support, but same misunderstanding. I have updated my question on the top.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is the [post__in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) option:

```
query_posts(array(
    'showposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'category_name' => 'MyCat',
    'post__in' => array(1, 2, 3, ...)
));
```

This allows you to define the specific post ID's that will be included in the query.

Note that this seems illogical to combine with `category_name` however, since you can specify the exact post ID's.

Comment: Thx for support. Maybe a misunderstanding too. I want to say to the random loop that this only will random the post 1 till 10 of for example 15 posts in an category. Does this really work like this? I have updated my question again - maybe this is more clear?

Comment: @Pepe - the question is very unclear, if both shennan and my answer are not what you are looking for.  Please clarify your question (I've read it again, but it's no clearer to me now than it was when I answered).